# How to deal with Model queries with constraints coming from multiple related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'n building a CMS like application, in which a `User` has_many `Report` which belong_to `Account`. There is also a `Deadline` model in between `User` and `Account`.

I'm now creating a dashboard in which I'd like to show an overview of accounts for which the User has created reports in the past few days. To complicate things, I'd also like to show Accounts for which the user has Deadlines.

My first approach was creating an instance method on the User model:

```
  def recent_accounts
    # find the accounts which where reported on the last 24 hours
    accounts = reports.where('date > ?', 24.hours.ago).select(:account_id).map(&:account_id).uniq
    dl = user_deadlines.all.select(:account_id).map(&:account_id).uniq
    Account.includes(:past_deadlines, :deadlines).find((accounts+dl).compact)
  end
```

While this works, it doesn't feel like this is the right thing to do. Since this is about accounts, I think I should refactor this into the Account model. Is that a correct assumption?

I was thinking about creating a conditonal scope for this, but am struggling on how to pull both information from the report relation and from the deadline relation at the same time.

I've read about using `merge` and `joins`, but can't really conceptualize a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Denormalize. Keep an `last_report_created_at` and a `deadline` flag on `Account`. Or can an account have deadlines from several users?
Keeping those values updated isn't hard compared to the gain of performance.

Comment: That would mean a lot of denormilization... I only want to find accounts that were dealt with by that specific user. If I'd follow this pattern, I'd need "last_report_created_at_by_x" types of attributes, one for each user. I don't feel like that is even remotely better than the solution I already found. Just looking to refactor this into something that runs from the Account Model.