# Is it possible to create OR Joins in Rails to fetch records that intersect with 2 different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I also posted a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613524?noredirect=1, which was more about this concept.

What I'm trying to do is the following: I want to find `Accounts` for which a certain `User` has created a `Report`, **or** for which a user has a `deadline`.

```
  scope :active_accounts_for_user, -> (user) {
    joins(:deadlines)
    .where(:deadlines => {user: [nil, user]})
    .joins(:reports)
    .where(:reports => {user: user, day: (Date.today - 1.day..Date.today)})
  }
```

Problem with this is that Rails created an AND query, so it will find only Accounts that both have a report and a deadline. That is obviously to restrictive for my usecase.

Edit: Ok, I found a solution, I'd like to confirm whether this is good practive though. I'm basically creating separate queries to both Models in order to fetch the account ID's, which I use in a simple where:

```
  scope :active_accounts_for_user, -> (user) {
    accounts_with_reports = Report.where(user: user).where('date > ?', 24.hours.ago).pluck(:account_id)
    accounts_with_deadlines = Deadline.where(user: user).pluck(:account_id)
    account_ids = (accounts_with_reports + accounts_with_deadlines).compact
    return includes(:past_deadlines, :deadlines).where(id: account_ids)
  }
```

Is this a correct use of a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use vanilla SQL.

If I understand your schema correctly, you are after something that requires left joins more than it requires the OR operator. The OR operator on an INNER JOIN will not achieve what you are hoping for, since any record that only have a deadline but no report will not be returned. Instead, LEFT JOIN returns you all the account records where there is a matching user_id in deadlines or reports tables.

```
select * from accounts 
left join deadlines on deadlines.user = accounts.user
left join reports on reports.user = accounts.user
where day ...
and (reports.user IS NOT NULL or deadline.user IS NOT NULL)
```

In Rails 4 I believe you can specify the SQL code for a join, while chaining the where clause as you would normally. So this would become:

```
joinsql = "left join deadlines on 
 deadlines.user = accounts.user
 left join reports 
 on reports.user = accounts.user"

Account.join(joinsql).where(
   accounts: {user: user}, 
   deadline: {day: (Date.today - 1.day..Date.today)}
 ).where("reports.user IS NOT NULL or deadlines.user IS NOT NULL")
```

You can then access the results for all the joined tables.

Note the addition of the second where clause chained to the first, effectively AND-ing the plain text condition to ensure that both reports and deadlines are not both blank.

If you have associations in place connecting the tables through the user attribute, then you may be able to use plain Active Record queries to use

```
Account.includes(:accounts).includes(:deadlines).where...
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Another option, avoiding LEFT JOIN is to use an inner join on one table and UNION with a similar query with an inner join on the other table. For this to work you have to specify the returned fields with `.select` to ensure a union can work. This is more tricky in my opinion.

Either way though it is often just easier to write the SQL up to the point of the where clause conditions that contain user entry, rather than trying to guess what Rails is going to do to create the query you want.

Comment: Won't Left Joins give me all the Accounts?

Comment: The where clause should cover that by limiting the user and day range if a deadline is set. That said, you'll need to extend the conditions to exclude results where both deadline and report are NULL. I'll edit my answer to include a possibility for this.

Comment: Thanks, great solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Rails 5.0 and higher.

There is a section in guidelines how to do it: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions

The only *catch* with joins is that they need to be duplicated both relations to make the whole query structurally compatible:

```
scope :active_accounts_for_user, -> (user) {
 joins(:deadlines).joins(:reports).where(deadlines: ...).or(
   joins(:deadlines).joins(:reports).where(reports: ...)
  )
}
```

Comment: Even though the link you mentioned might solve the question, but it is more appropriate to include the relevant part of code here too. Otherwise, it could well be a comment on the question only.

Comment: This only works in Rails 5 unfortunataly. Is there a Rails 4 equivalent?

Comment: It was added in rails 5.0 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md
Previous versions don't support or queries. The need to be written using pure SQL.

Comment: You could try [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or) which implements `or` method for Rails 3 and Rails 4